# Selecting multiple tables MySQL and retrieving different data

Tags: php, sql

I have 4 tables that I need to pull data from. I need to count how many people are signed for a single event and see if a user is applied for an event.

These are my table setups:

```
TABLE: users
+----+----------+-------+--------+-------+
| id | username | level | class  | guild |
+----+----------+-------+--------+-------+
| 1  | example1 | 100   | Hunter | blah  |
| 2  | example2 | 105   | Mage   | blah2 |
| 3  | example3 | 102   | Healer | blah  |
+----+----------+-------+--------+-------+
ID is primary

TABLE: event_randoms
+----+----------+-------+--------+----------+----------+
| id | username | level | class  | apped_by | event_id |
+----+----------+-------+--------+----------+----------+
| 1  | random1  |  153  | Hunter |    3     |    3     |
| 2  | random2  |  158  | Healer |    3     |    1     |
| 3  | random3  |  167  | Warrior|    1     |    3     |
+----+----------+-------+--------+----------+----------+
ID is primary
apped_by should be foreign key to users.id
event_id should be foreign key to events.id

TABLE: events
+----+------------+------------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| id | event_name | event_date | initiator | min_level | max_level |
+----+------------+------------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| 1  |   event1   |    date1   |     1     |    100    |     120   |
| 2  |   event2   |    date2   |     1     |    121    |     135   |
| 3  |   event3   |    date3   |     1     |    100    |     120   |
| 4  |   event4   |    date4   |     1     |    150    |     200   |
+----+------------+------------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
ID is primary

TABLE: event_apps
+----+----------+--------------+
| id | event_id | applicant_id |
+----+----------+--------------+
| 1  |    3     |      2       |
| 2  |    4     |      2       |
| 3  |    3     |      1       |
| 4  |    1     |      3       |
+----+----------+--------------+
ID is primary
event_id should be foreign key to events.id
applicant_id should be foreign key to users.id
```

I will be the first to admit that I am very new to this. I just learned how to use MySQL a few days ago. I can grab stuff from a single table, but I am unsure how to grab from multiple tables.

This is the SQL query I tried

```
SELECT DD_events.id, event_id, applicant_id, guild, level, class, DD_users.id
      FROM DD_events, DD_event_apps, DD_users
      WHERE DD_event_apps.event_id = DD_events.id
      AND DD_event_apps.applicant_id = DD_users.id
```

and tried to print_r an array but the array turns up empty.

So a few questions pertain to this:
1: How would I count and display as a number how many people (users and randoms) are signed up for an event? 
eg: event 3 should have 4 total (2 users and 2 randoms)

2: How do I see if a particular individual is signed for an event and display text based if they are or not?
eg: user 1 is signed up for event 3 so it would be "Registered" but user 2, who is not signed, would display "Not Registered"

3: I want to display info for who is signed for a particular event in 2 tables, 1 for users and another for randoms. 
eg: Event 3 would have 2 users info (username, guild, class, level) under the users table and then 2 random users info (name, class, level, what user applied this person) in the random table.

Any and all help is appreciated even if you can answer 1 part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm thinking this would be your base query:

```
SELECT
    event.id,
    app.applicant_id,
    usr.guild,
    usr.level,
    usr.class,
    usr.id AS Userid
FROM
    DD_events event
JOIN
    DD_event_apps app
    ON  (event.id = app.event_id)
LEFT JOIN
    DD_users usr
    ON  (app.user_id = usr.id)
```

You can make modifications to this to aggregate it, like so:

```
SELECT
    event.id,
    COUNT(app.applicant_id) AS ApplicantCount,
    COUNT(DISTINCT usr.guild) AS UniqueGuilds,
    COUNT(DISTINCT usr.level) AS UniqueLevels,
    COUNT(DISTINCT usr.class) AS UniqueClasses,
    COUNT(DISTINCT usr.id) AS UniqueUsers
FROM
    DD_events event
JOIN
    DD_event_apps app
    ON  (event.id = app.event_id)
LEFT JOIN
    DD_users usr
    ON  (app.user_id = usr.id)
GROUP BY
    event.id
```

I could write those scripts for you, but I think this provides a good starting point for you to continue from. You'll find that T-SQL is fairly simple when you are trying to get the results you are looking for. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the base. If you wouldn't mind me asking, can you comment on what each thing does? Are you setting key words by doing `DD_Events event`? I am also completely lost on the 2nd query.

Comment: @Matt With `DD_Events events`, 'events' is an alias, so you don't have to reference the full table name in the query. All the first one is doing to joining your data together similar to what you were attempting in your query. The second one allows you to count `COUNT(...)` or uniquely count `COUNT(DISTINCT ...)` the records in each column returned by the query.

Does this help?

Comment: That is a cool trick. How would I choose a specific event by event number? Would I just add `WHERE event.id = 3`?

Comment: @Matt - Great if it helped and answered your question, be sure to mark it as answered.

Comment: Sorry, thought I could hit enter to do a new line. I was wrong. Lol. I edited my last comment.

Comment: @Matt - To filter on a specific event, you would add `WHERE event.id = 3` (for event id 3, of course). If you are using the aggregated query (with the counts), the `WHERE` clause must go before the `GROUP BY`

Comment: Thank you. I think I have a handle on it. I will comment if I have any further questions.

Comment: Ok. I got the user table to populate correctly. I am however stuck on the part where I need to see if they are applied in an event while in the event list to say 'Applied' in the proper column. Also having trouble on counting the total number of people enrolled in an event.

Comment: @Matt - Based on how this is joined (inner join), everyone in the result set has applied. I am basing this off of an assumption that the DD_event_apps table contains only users who applied for an event.

Comment: Should something like this work: `$sql = mysql_query("SELECT count(*) FROM DD_event_apps WHERE event_id = $row['event_id']")or die(mysql_error());` EDIT: I get an error `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE, expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or T_NUM_STRING in /mnt/500gb/html/s/host/skullmonkey/DD/events.php on line 73 `

Comment: @Matt - That would give you the number of applicants. Put curly brackets around your variable: `event_id = {$row['event_id']}"`

Comment: When using `SELECT count(*) AS numbuh FROM DD_event_apps WHERE event_id = {$row['event_id']}` it returns this error `Failed to run query: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1`. I don't see where I have made an error.

Comment: @Matt - Try hardcoding a value for the event_id to see if that still errors out. If it works, then do this: `$eventid = $row['event_id'];

$sql = mysql_query("SELECT count(*) FROM DD_event_apps WHERE event_id = $eventid")or die(mysql_error());`

Comment: Did not work. `$fubar = "3";
$query = "SELECT count(*) AS numbuh FROM DD_event_apps WHERE event_id = $fubar";`

Comment: @Matt - Can you add `echo $query;` and tell me what is echoed? It's an error in the SQL, but we'll need to see what is being passed to find the problem.

Comment: Turns out that I needed to clear my cache. (Weird but ok.) I have it working with `$query = "SELECT count(*) AS numbuh FROM DD_event_apps WHERE event_id = {$row['id']}";` but it returns blank. An `echo($query);` returns `SELECT count(*) AS numbuh FROM DD_event_apps WHERE event_id = 13` (where the id numbers change.) I'm going to post the entire block of code in a response so you can see what I am doing.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21899/discussion-between-matt-and-nicarus)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php $query = "SELECT count(*) AS numbuh FROM DD_event_apps WHERE event_id = {$row['id']}";
try
{
    // These two statements run the query against your database table.
    $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
    $stmt->execute();
}
catch(PDOException $ex)
{
    // Note: On a production website, you should not output $ex->getMessage().
    // It may provide an attacker with helpful information about your code. 
    die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage());
}
echo($query);
// Finally, we can retrieve all of the found rows into an array using fetchAll
$count = $stmt->fetchAll();
echo($count['numbuh']); ?>
```